# Symfony2 / FOSUserBundle - Disallowing users from getting to anonymous pages

Tags: symfony, firewall, fosuserbundle, rules

I've noticed that FOSUserBundle's default access_control configuration is

```
- { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

But when I try to set these roles to

```
IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY && !IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY
```

it gives me endless loops to /login. How can I make only these three rules to be forbidden for fully authenticated users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not deny access for the login page when the user is logged in, because a 403 forbidden will redirect automatically to login page because it request the user to login.

Better you write a service that checks every request. When it matches login request you need to check if the user is authenticated and redirect him to index page instead to the requested login page.